# Display Object record information in visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, map, collection-variable

I have a map `UserTest <Id, List<String>>` which displays the User ID and related permission sets assigned to each of the users in the Visualforce page.

[image]

I need to also display other relevant information like lastname, firstname, department, division of these users as columns present in the map in the visualforce page.

Attached is an image of the current visualforce page.

Please suggest what should be the logic to get the required output.

Comment: Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/392258/edit) your question and add minimal required code.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take our [tour] and read [ask] and [help/on-topic] to learn about our community's expectations. Then, [edit] your post to ask a _specific, detailed question_ about a problem in your current implementation. Remember, the community will not create code for you.

Comment: Make wrapper class with your required parameters & then use Map<Id, wrapperobject>...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Visualforce, you can easily map different maps in the same iteration. For example, let's say we presume that you have the following properties:

```
public Map<Id, List<String>> userPermissionSets { get; set; }
public Map<Id, User> userDetails { get; set; }
public Id[] userIds { get; set; }
```

An appropriate initialization might look like:

```
// Default constructor
public MyClassName() {
  userDetails = new Map<Id, User>([
    SELECT FIELDS(STANDARD) FROM User WHERE IsActive = true
  ]);
  userPermissionSets = new Map<Id, List<String>>();
  userIds = new Id[0];
  for(User record: userDetails.values()) {
    userPermissionSets.put(record.Id, new String[0]);
    userIds.add(record.Id);
  }
  for(PermissionSetAssignment assignment: [
    SELECT FIELDS(STANDARD) 
    FROM PermissionSetAssignment
    WHERE AssigneeId = :userIds AND IsOwnedByProfile = FALSE
  ]) {
    userPermissionSets.get(record.AssigneeId).add(record.Name);
  }
}
```

Now, In your Visualforce code, you can reference everything by using the `userIds` list:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!userIds}" var="userId">
  <apex:column value="{!userDetails[userId].Name}" />
  <apex:column value="{!userDetails[userId].UserName}" />
  <apex:column value="{!userPermissionSets[userId]}" />
  <!-- etc -->
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

One word of caution: if you do this, make sure all maps contain every key (in our example, we do this by initializing the maps properly first). If you don't, your page will have an unhandled exception about a missing key, and the page won't render at all.

Comment: Life Saver. I didn't know that we can display multiple maps in VF in same iteration loop. Many thanks!!